# JSONDecodeError when scraping URL

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I received an error

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

when I try to get the content of:

```
import json
import requests
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


url = 'https://www.sportsbookreview.com/ms-odds-v2/odds-v2-service?query={%20openingLines(eid:%203771018,%20mtid:%20401,%20paid:%2020)%20lineHistory(eid:%203771018,%20mtid:%20401,%20paid:%2020,%20partid:%20[450,%201207])%20{%20lines%20}%20}'
dt = timedelta(hours=4)  # adjust to your timezone

data = requests.get(url).json()

print(json.loads(data, indent=4))
```

I'm not sure why because when I open the page, I can see the data in JSON.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The website you want to track seems to be using blocking certain `User-Agent` headers like that of pythons `urllib` that `requests.get()` uses by default. It sent you some DDoS protection webpage instead of JSON response you were hoping for. I used following code to mock a genuine browser request to bypass that:

```
import json
import requests
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

header = {"user-agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X x.y; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0"} 

url = 'https://www.sportsbookreview.com/ms-odds-v2/odds-v2-service?query={%20openingLines(eid:%203771018,%20mtid:%20401,%20paid:%2020)%20lineHistory(eid:%203771018,%20mtid:%20401,%20paid:%2020,%20partid:%20[450,%201207])%20{%20lines%20}%20}'
dt = timedelta(hours=4)  # adjust to your timezone

data = requests.get(url, headers = header).json()

print(data)
```